# Why does Angular js assignment operators like below doesn't work in Controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I see some of the assignment operators doesn't work in AngularJS controller.. More details below...

```
<div ng-app="calculator" ng-init="math.element1=1.2222;math.element2=2.3333" ng-controller="DoMath as math">
  <b>Add Two Elements:</b>
  <div>
    Element 1: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="math.element1">
  </div>
  <div>
    Element 2: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="math.element2">
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>Sum (Rounded to two digits):</b> {{math.sum() | number:2 }}
    <br>Multiplication (Rounded to two digits):</b> {{math.multiply() | number:2 }}
    <br>Division (Rounded to two digits):</b> {{math.divide() | number:2 }} 
    <br>{{ math.name }}  <!-- Prints name -->
    <br>{{ math.someelement }} <!-- prints nothing  -->
  </div>
</div>


angular.module('calculator', [])
.controller('DoMath', function() {
  this.name = "hello";  // Works
  this.someelement = this.element1; // doesn't work
  this.sum = function() { return  (this.element1 + this.element2) };
  this.multiply = function() { return  (this.element1 * this.element2) };
  this.divide = function() { return  (this.element1 / this.element2) };
});
```

Why does

```
this.someelement = this.element1;
```

assignment operator doesn't work ?

See code in action here http://jsfiddle.net/anil614sagar/z1a8ze4b/

Comment: I don't know, but `this.someelement = this.element1 + 0;` changes things a bit

Comment: About the usage of ng-init: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit and how it's not the best way to use it in your case.

Answer (score 1):

`element1` is a primitive.  At the time of the Controller's initialization, `this.element1` is undefined, so `this.someelement` simply becomes `undefined`.  If you want to map the values of two controller properties together, you have to do so using objects rather than primitives so that the prototype chain works.

[This article provides some explanation](http://www.codelord.net/2014/05/10/understanding-angulars-magic-dont-bind-to-primitives/)

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('calculator', []).controller('DoMath', function ($scope) {


    $scope.$watch('element1', function () {

        this.someelement = this.element1;

    }.bind(this));

    ...

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z1a8ze4b/1/)